# decrypt xored content in binary

Tags: encryption, binary, xor

I want to decrypt a xored content. if you want you can download the file in [here](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B6f2TGvXkv0pMDhxdFlaS0E0QTQ&export=download)

the file extension is .bin but content looks like hex to me and not binary, i'm not sure what kind of content it's.
the content look likes bellow:

> 2007 0b54 180a 541d 1318 1a00 541c 0654
>   0a0c 0606 065a 9854 0caa 2624 3000 0c04
>   260c 102c b435 fcaa b2ab acbf 32b2 aeb9
>   34b9 a0a8 a425 b6a9 809c bcb7 a8bb 2e34
>   eaa7 a835 80aa 8625 b8a7 aebc 2cbb 9e9d
>   329c bcaf 3493 a080 a625 aab9 329c bcaf
>   34b1 aab6 aab3 3431 b0a8 bebf b6ad 3634
>   b0af 849d 329c b225 faab acba b4af 3a93
>   32aa a0a9 a6b3 b80a 0a

and if it's hex why each 4 character is space delimiter-ed?
i think it can't be base64, because when i try to run following code i will get error

```
a@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ base64 -d enigma.bin>enigma.txt
base64: invalid input
```

second my goal is to find the key. so I tried the xortool

```
a@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ xortool enigma.bin
The most probable key lengths:
   3:   15.1%
   6:   19.3%
   9:   13.6%
  12:   15.3%
  15:   9.4%
  18:   10.9%
  20:   4.4%
  24:   5.3%
  30:   3.4%
  36:   3.4%
Key-length can be 3*n
Most possible char is needed to guess the key!
```

so i tried most used character like space(20) or E T A O I N S H R D L U but i had not luck. still my guess is i got the encoding incorrect

Comment: You could remove the whitespace, convert Hex to bytes and run your analysis on that.

Comment: the 2-bytes of hex and then a space thing is just how you're displaying it, the binary doesn't have any of that. in the node repl: `> console.log(fs.readFileSync('./enigma.bin'))`
`<Buffer 20 07 0b 54 18 0a 54 1d 13 18 1a 00 54 1c 06 54 0a 0c 06 06 06 5a 98 54 0c aa 26 24 30 00 0c 04 26 0c 10 2c b4 35 fc aa b2 ab ac bf 32 b2 ae b9 34 b9 ... >`